# PHP div with two Id

Tags: php, html, mysql

I got a page where you can add products, parts, material and packaging. When the sort (pm_sort) is selected on product it should show the product information but when selected parts it should also show product information. i got the following code:

```
<select required  class='selectpicker form-control border' name='pm_sort' id='pm_sort' value="<?php echo isset($_POST['pm_sort']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['pm_sort'], ENT_QUOTES) : "";  ?>">
               <option selected="true" disabled="disabled" value="">Select sort...</option>
                   <option>Product</option>
                   <option>Material</option>
                   <option>Part</option>
                   <option>Packaging</option>        
           </select>

<div class='Product' id='Product' || id='Part'>
   <h3>Product information</h3>
<input type='text' name='pm_code' class='form-control' value="<?php echo isset($_POST['pm_code']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['pm_code'], ENT_QUOTES) : "";  ?>" />
</div>

<div class='material' id='material'>
   <h3>Material information</h3>
<input type='text' name='pm_code_m' class='form-control' value="<?php echo isset($_POST['pm_code_m']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['pm_code_m'], ENT_QUOTES) : "";  ?>" />
</div>

<div class='Packaging' id='Packaging'>
   <h3>Material information</h3>
<input type='text' name='pm_code_p' class='form-control' value="<?php echo isset($_POST['pm_code_p']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['pm_code_p'], ENT_QUOTES) : "";  ?>" />
</div>


<script type='text/javascript'>
$('div').hide()

$('#pm_sort').change(function () {
     var value = this.value;
   $('div').hide()
   $('#' + this.value).show();
});
</script>
```

The question is:
How can I get the same page information based on the select value Part or Product?

Comment: You haven't asked a question or described any kind of problem. Please be specific about what you need help with. P.S. `id='Product' || id='Part'` is not valid syntax in HTML. I would guess this is related to the issue, but it's not clear precisely what you want to ask us about.

Comment: You can have multiple classes, you can't have multiple `id`s. Maybe `<div class='Product Part' id="unique_identifier">` is what you want

Comment: The question is how i can get  "When the sort (pm_sort) is selected on product it should show the product information but when selected parts it should also show product information."

Comment: An edit button is provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add an if statement to check if the value select is named part and then still show product information:

```
<select required  class='selectpicker form-control border' name='pm_sort' id='pm_sort' value="<?php echo isset($_POST['pm_sort']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['pm_sort'], ENT_QUOTES) : "";  ?>">
               <option selected="true" disabled="disabled" value="">Select sort...</option>
                   <option>Product</option>
                   <option>Material</option>
                   <option>Part</option>
                   <option>Packaging</option>        
           </select>

<div class='Product' id='Product' || id='Part'>
   <h3>Product information</h3>
<input type='text' name='pm_code' class='form-control' value="<?php echo isset($_POST['pm_code']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['pm_code'], ENT_QUOTES) : "";  ?>" />
</div>

<div class='material' id='material'>
   <h3>Material information</h3>
<input type='text' name='pm_code_m' class='form-control' value="<?php echo isset($_POST['pm_code_m']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['pm_code_m'], ENT_QUOTES) : "";  ?>" />
</div>

<div class='Packaging' id='Packaging'>
   <h3>Material information</h3>
<input type='text' name='pm_code_p' class='form-control' value="<?php echo isset($_POST['pm_code_p']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['pm_code_p'], ENT_QUOTES) : "";  ?>" />
</div>


<script type='text/javascript'>
$('div').hide()

$('#pm_sort').change(function () {
     var value = this.value;
   $('div').hide()
   if(value == "Part"){
       $('#Product').show();
   }else{
       $('#' + value).show();
   }
});
</script>
```